# How to apply JavaScript in real life

Tags: javascript

So I'm new to computer science and programming, and I've recently learned Javascript, and though I've seen all the incredible things I can do with it, I haven't actually figured out how to do those things. I was wondering if anyone could give any suggestions to help me out with some interesting and applicable ways I can use my Javascript knowledge.

Thanks!

Comment: javascript is the frontier of web communication :D.. but on a side note.. we don't ask these vague questions here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of beginner projects. The best way to learn will be to build something. Either think of a real world problem that you would like to solve or use some of the provided links for some inspiration:

[Beginner JS projects - strongdan](https://github.com/strongdan/beginner-js-projects)
[Beginner JS projects - romeojeremiah](https://github.com/romeojeremiah/javascript-projects-for-beginners)